# How can I remove the global array by using preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I need to set some discontinuous bits in register `GPIO0_SET_DATA23`. I want to index these bits as 0, 1, ...

Currently I am using a global array to save the bit locations, and `#define SET_LED(X)`.

Here is the `.c` code:

```
int led_bits[5] = {8, 9, 23, 24, 27};
```

Here is the `.h` code:

```
extern int led_bits[];
#define SET_LED(X) (GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = 1 << led_bits[X])
```

How I can implement this without the global array in preprocessor? I only call `SET_LED` with constant integer. I will not call it as `SET_LED(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

In C99 or later, you could use an array literal (and a `static inline` function):

```
static inline void SET_LED(int X)
{
    GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = 1 << (int [5]){8, 9, 23, 24, 27}[X];
}
```

This sets a global variable — that's a tad ugly.  It might be better to use:

```
static inline int SET_LED(int X)
{
    return 1 << (int [5]){8, 9, 23, 24, 27}[X];
}
```

and then:

```
GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = SET_LED(4);
```

or whatever it is that you need.  This will also allow you to use a variable for the number; using `#define LED0 8` etc will not allow that (though you do explicitly state that variable support will not be necessary). It might be a good idea to add bounds checking to the inline function.  One advantage of the `#define` system is that if you try `SET_LED(6)` but there is no `LED6` macro, the code won't compile.

If you're working on an embedded system without C99 or later support, you will need to use an alternative mechanism; this will not work with (most) C90 compilers.

Note that when you have an optimizing compiler and a constant argument to the function, the compiler will be able to calculate the value as if you'd written:

```
GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = 1 << 27;
```

where the shifted value will be calculated (as 134,217,728 — in a locale where commas are used as thousands separators) at compile time too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the reason you're trying to avoid a global array but you can modify your macro to use a pointer and an index instead.

```
#define SET_LED(p, x) (GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = 1 << p[x])
```

Then when you want to call SET_LED you can pass it your array like so:

```
int led_bits[5] = {8, 9, 23, 24, 27};
SET_LED(led_bits, x);
```

That way you avoid having to use `extern int led_bits[];` in your header.

Comment: I don't want the `led_bits` array itself. The only way I found out is to list all the indices: `#define SET_LED_0 (GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = 1 << 8) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to do it:

```
#define LED0 8
#define LED1 9
#define LED2 23
#define LED3 24
#define LED4 27

#define SET_LED(X) (GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = 1 << LED##X)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the pre-processor here. An ordinary function will do just fine.

```
inline void
set_led(const int x)
{
  const int bits[] = {8, 9, 23, 24, 27};
  GPIO0_SET_DATA23 = (1U << bits[x]);
}
```

If you call `set_led` with a literal argument, GCC will optimize it away to just a single store of the pre-computed value so there is no overhead compared to using a macro.

To proof, here is the assembly generated by GCC when compiling

```
#define GPIO0_SET_DATA23 (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0xdeadbeef))

/* set_led as above */

int
test()
{
  set_led(3);
  return 0;
}
```

with `-O2`:

```
test:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $3735928559, %eax
    movl    $16777216, (%rax)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that my compiler(ti-cgt-c6000_8.0.3) ignore the inline keyword even in -O2.